# Get Oracle Package Procedure Parameters with Java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to fetch the parameters of a given Oracle procedure in a given package. It's always returns no data.

Our logic works fine when fetching the parameters of a procedure that is NOT in a package. I expected this to just work. since it asks for a package name I didn't expect to have to do anything else.

Once I have a connection we run this:

```
dbMetaData = conn.getMetaData();
rs = dbMetaData.getProcedureColumns(packageName, null, procedureName, null);
while(rs.next()){
  ...
}
```

rs.next is always false. I must be missing something?

Comment: *"since it asks for a package name"* Where does the [`getProcedureColumns(String catalog, String schemaPattern, String procedureNamePattern, String columnNamePattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getProcedureColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method ask for a *package* name?

Comment: Sorry, I'm certainly not an Oracle expert. I thought an oracle package was applicable as catalog. Once we get the params we use SimpleJdbcCall to execute the procedure. On the SimpleJdbcCall class there is a method called "withCatalogName". 

The java doc for that reads: Optionally, specify the name of the catalog that contins the stored procedure. 

To provide consistency with the Oracle DatabaseMetaData, this is used to specify the package name if the procedure is declared as part of a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found that this call works if you pass the schema in the schema pattern field. Without a schema, oracle packages won't be found.

rs = dbMetaData.getProcedureColumns(packageName, schemaName, procedureName, "%");

Comment: If this has solved your issue then fine but this is not true. Use of `schemaPattern` here is kind of filter. When `NULL` means the schema name is not used to narrow the search. It doesn't mean that it will not search your procedure. You can check Oracle docs for `DatabaseMetaData`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get all the columns of the procedure, right ? So you should use `%` instead of `null`. Try to change your code as shown below and try again:

```
rs = dbMetaData.getProcedureColumns(packageName, null, procedureName, "%");
```

Comment: Not completely, but it helped. See my posted answer that solved it eventually.